# Why is pthread_join not returning?

Tags: c, linux, multithreading, sockets, pthreads

I think pthread_join should always return a value and then allow the main thread to process code after that. In my past experience, this will work. But now I am stuck with it. Somehow it just doesn't return and block the main thread. Or may it is the main thread that executes the task. I don't know why. In the code below, I cannot reach "Thread created2" until I terminate the client. Any idea?

```
int main(int argc, char *argv[]) {

    int sockfd, port;  /* listen on sock_fd, new connection on new_fd */
    struct sockaddr_in my_addr;    /* my address information */
    struct sockaddr_in their_addr; /* connector's address information */
    socklen_t sin_size;

    if(signal(SIGINT, sigintEvent) == SIG_ERR)
        printf("can't catch SIGINT!");

    /* generate the socket */
    if ((sockfd = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0)) == -1) {
        perror("socket");
        exit(1);
    }

    if (argc > 1) {
        port = atoi(argv[1]);
    } else {
        port = MYPORT;
    }

    /* generate the end point */
    my_addr.sin_family = AF_INET;         /* host byte order */
    my_addr.sin_port = htons(port);     /* short, network byte order */
    my_addr.sin_addr.s_addr = INADDR_ANY; /* auto-fill with my IP */
    /* bzero(&(my_addr.sin_zero), 8);   ZJL*/     /* zero the rest of the struct */

    /* bind the socket to the end point */
    if (bind(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&my_addr, sizeof(struct sockaddr)) \
            == -1) {
        perror("bind");
        exit(1);
    }

    /* start listnening */
    if (listen(sockfd, MAXCONNECTIONS) == -1) {
        perror("listen");
        exit(1);
    }

    createPool(MAXCONNECTIONS);

    /* create a node pointer as head of the list */
    head = (node*)malloc(sizeof(node));

    openFile();

    printf("server starts listnening ...\n");

    int new_fd;
    sin_size = sizeof(struct sockaddr_in);

    while((new_fd = accept(sockfd, (struct sockaddr *)&their_addr, &sin_size))) {
        printf("Accepted!\n");
        printf("server: got connection!\n");

        //tNode* tThread = (tNode*)threadDequeue();

        pthread_t pt;

        printf("Got tThread.\n");

        if((pthread_create(&pt, NULL, runService,(void*)&new_fd)) != 0) {
            printf("error creating thread.");
            abort();
        }

        printf("Thread created.\n");

        if( pthread_join(pt, NULL) != 0 ) {
            printf("error joining thread");
            abort();
        }

        printf("Thread created2.\n");
    }

    exit(1);
}
```

Comment: What's `runService` doing? Whatever it's doing, it's probably not returning and the main thread can't continue until it finishes.

Comment: Maybe you should start considering accepting answers from people who put effort in helping you...

Answer (score 5):

From the documentation we can read the following information about [pthread_join](http://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man3/pthread_join.3.html)

> The pthread_join() function **waits** for the thread specified by
>   thread
>          to terminate.  If that thread has already terminated, then
>          pthread_join() returns immediately.  The thread specified by thread
>          must be joinable.

This indicates that in your case parent thread is waiting for the completion of its child thread **pt**. The child thread **pt** which is executing the `runService` is still not returned/completed. Hence your parent thread would keep on waiting for completion( not returning from pthread_join method).

You should try to review the code of `runService` to understand this situation.